# Save a selected row into a new shapefile with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, shapefile, export, cursor

I have a shapefile with 100+ rows. What I like to do is to select each row and export all its data to a new shapefile. I tried using the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` as follows:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputshape,"*",None) as cursor:
...     for row in cursor:
...         arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(row,pathToFolder,row[3] + ".shp")
```

Resulting in an error, arcpy displays following message:

> Runtime error 
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "", line 3, in 
>       File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1694, in
>   FeatureClassToFeatureClass
>       raise e
>       RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool

I think first parameter in the `FeatureClassTofeatureClass_conversion` method ist wrong. Other Examples show that there has to be the @Shape field. the workflow I would like to automate is very simple: 1) Open the attribute table 2) select a row 3) Export selected data to a new shapefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cursor does not select anything, it is only returning a tuple (~a list of the attributes). But you can use the ObjectID returned by the cursor and pass this to [Select](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm):

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
>   typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
>   and stores them in an output feature class.

Like this:

```
import arcpy,os

input_fc=r'C:\TEST\Shape.shp'
outfolder=r'C:\folder'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(input_fc,'OID@') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        sql="""{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(input_fc, arcpy.Describe(
            input_fc).OIDFieldName),row[0])
        arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=input_fc, out_feature_class=os.path.join(outfolder,'Shapefile_{0}.shp'.format(row[0])), 
                             where_clause=sql)
```

[image]

But an easier option would be to use tool [Split By Attributes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm#) with ObjectID field as split field:

> Splits an input dataset by unique attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your first provided option works brilliantly! Later on, I will have a look on your suggested second option!

Answer (score 1):

To export each row/feature within the cursor you will need to nest a variable expression that queries the active cursor row FID or some other unique identifier field/value.  Then you may use the [Select](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/select.htm) method using the active row expression aka where clause to export out the active row to a new fc.

The pseudo logic would go something like this:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputshape,'FID') as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        where_clause = # define expression here for active field/row
        # Execute Select
        arcpy.Select_analysis(inputshape, out_feature_class, where_clause) # you'll have to define the out_feature_class
```

Comment: @Andi90 updated answer